# Creating a corpus from different JSON files

Tags: python, json, loops, pandas

I would like to create a corpus composed by the body of different articles stored in a JSON format. They are in different files named after the year, for example:

```
with open('Scot_2005.json') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

corresponds to a newspaper, Scotsman for the year 2005. Moreover, the rest of the files for this newspaper are named: `APJ_2006`.... `APJ2015`. Also. I have another newspaper, Scottish Daily Mail, that goes only from the years 2014-1015: `SDM_2014, SDM_2015`. I would like to create a common list with the body of all these articles:

```
doc_set = [d['body'] for d in data]
```

My problem is looping the first part of the code that I posted so that data corresponds to all articles rather than just the ones from a given newspaper at a given year. Any ideas of how to accomplish this task? In my attempt I try using Pandas such:

```
for i in range(2005,2016):
    df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('Scot_%d.json' % i)])

doc_set = df.body
```

The problem with this method seems to me to be: it does not append all years; I am not sure how to include other newspapers with time intervals other than from 2005-15. The outcome of this method looks like:

```
date
2015-12-31    The Institute of Directors (IoD) has added its...
2015-12-31    It is startling to see how much the Holyrood l...
2015-12-31    A hike in interest rates in the new year will ...
2015-12-31    The First Minister has resolved to make 2016 a...
2015-12-30    The Scottish Government announced yesterday th...
2015-12-30    The Footsie closed lower amid falling oil pric...
2015-12-28    BEFORE we start the guessing game for 2016, a ...
2015-12-27    AS WE ushered in 2015, few would have predicte...
2015-12-23    No matter how hard Derek McInnes and his Aberd...
2015-12-21    THE HEAD of a Scottish Government task force s...
2015-12-17    A Scottish local authority has fought off a le...
2015-12-17    Markets lifted after the Federal Reserve hiked...
2015-12-17    Significant increases in UK quotas for fish in...
2015-12-17    WAR of words with Donald Trump suggests its ti...
2015-12-16    SCOTLAND'S national performance companies have...
2015-12-15    Markets jumped ahead of what investors expect ...
2015-12-14    Political uncertainty in back seat as transpor...
2015-12-11    The International Monetary Fund (IMF) has warn...
2015-12-08    Scotland has a "spring in its step" with the j...
2015-12-07    London's leading share index struggled for dir...
2015-12-03    REDUCING carbon is just the start of it, write...
2015-11-26    One of the country's most prized salmon rivers...
2015-11-23    Tax and legislative changes undermine strong f...
2015-11-23    A second House of Lords committee has called f...
2015-11-14    At first glance, Scotland's economic performan...
2015-11-13    THE United States has long been viewed as the ...
2015-11-12    IT IS vital for a new governance group to rest...
2015-11-12    Former SSE chief Ian Marchant has criticised r...
2015-11-11    Telecoms firm TalkTalk said it will take a hit...
2015-11-09    Improvements to consumer rights legislation ma...
                                    ...                        
2015-02-25    Traders baulked at an assault on the 7,000 lev...
2015-02-24    BRITISH military personnel are to be deployed ...
2015-02-20    DAVID Cameron has announced a £859 million inv...
2015-02-16    Falling oil prices and slowing inflation have ...
2015-02-14    DEFENCE spending cuts and falling oil prices h...
2015-02-14    Brent crude rallied to a 2015 high and helped ...
2015-02-12    THE HOUSING markets in Scotland and Northern I...
2015-02-10    INVESTMENT in Scotland's commercial property m...
2015-02-09    Investors took flight after Greece's new gover...
2015-02-01    Experts say large numbers are delaying decisio...
2015-01-29    MORE than 300 jobs are at risk after Tesco sai...
2015-01-27    THE Three Bears have hit out at the Rangers bo...
2015-01-21    GEORGE Osborne has challenged the right of SNP...
2015-01-19    Employment figures this week should show Briti...
2015-01-19    Why haven't petrol pump prices fallen as fast ...
2015-01-18    Without an agreement on immediate action,  the...
2015-01-17    A SECOND independence referendum could be trig...
2015-01-14    THE RETAILER, which like its rivals has come u...
2015-01-14    HOUSE prices in Scotland rose by more than 4 p...
2015-01-13    HOUSE builder Taylor Wimpey is preparing for a...
2015-01-13    Supermarket group Sainsbury's today said it wo...
2015-01-13    INFLATION has tumbled to its lowest level on r...
2015-01-12    BUSINESSES are bullish about their ­prospects ...
2015-01-11    FOR decades, oil has dripped through our natio...
2015-01-09    Shares in the housebuilding sector fell heavil...
2015-01-08    THE Bank of England is expected to leave inter...
2015-01-05    COMPANIES in Scotland are more optimistic abou...
2015-01-04    UK is doing OK, but uncertainty looms on mid-y...
2015-01-02    The London market began the new year in a subd...
2015-01-02    The famous election mantra of Bill Clinton's c...
Name: body, dtype: object
```

Comment: So where is the [mcve] of *your attempt* to do that, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to loop over either newspaper names or years. Maybe try that?

Comment: @jonrshape, I just updated the question, as you can see by using Pandas I am not able to produce a list

Comment: No, you get a `DataFrame`, which is **exactly what you asked for**. What's the problem?!

Comment: I am then producint a list? the problem is to integrate another newspaper, for example the Scottish Daily Mail from the years 2014-15.

Comment: If you're using pandas, *go and read their documentation*. If you want a list, maybe don't use pandas? Either way, I've wasted enough time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a file list:

```
file_name_list = ( 'Scot_2005.json', 'APJ_2006.json' )
```

You can `append` to a list like this:

```
data = list()
for file_name in file_name_list:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
        for line in json_file:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
```

If you want to create the `file_name_list` programmatically, you can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) library.